# Using Excel to make a grid in millimeters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Trying to figure out a way to make a grid in Excel that will print out in with spacing of mm's.  Haven't figured out a way to do this yet though.

I'm doing some work with Nanoblocks (which a single 1x1 is 4mm x 4mm), and I want to have a grid to work with, I might even layout the design in Excel (just filling cells), but this later part will be manual, just really need the correctly sized grid (printed).

Comment: Keep in mind the printer itself is going to have a lot to do with the precision of the grid printed.

Comment: As it turns out, Excel does some rounding, which keeps it from having a precise mm size...  (Another thing for anyone else, which I did ensure, is to make sure that your printer settings are set to NOT scale the page to fit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the default measurement to mm:

- **File** Tab -> **Options** -> **Advanced** Tab -> **Display** Section -> **Ruler Units**
- Select `Millimeters`

To change the column/row width/height(in mm):

- **View** tab -> **Page Layout**
- Select all cells
- Right-Click on Columns -> **Column Width...**
- Right-Click on Rows -> **Row Height...**

Comment: Great answer. Only thing that could make it better would be some screenshots.

Comment: Ran into 2 issues:

-Couldn't print a "blank" page (I have grids on it).  Adding a "." to the bottom, right hand square allowed it to print.

-Excel apparently won't let you set a height/width of 4mm, it changes it to 3.97mm (small amount for 1 square, but over several, it gets way off).

Comment: @BondUniverse Adding some spaces to cells should allow a blank page to be printed. As to the 3.97mm, I just looked and apparently Excel will round the number down to the nearest .265 mm. (.265*15=3.975)

Comment: @bobSmith1432 While I really need a precise 4mm for my purposes, unless someone gives a better answer soon, I'll mark yours as accepted, chocking the rounding off to an annoying Excel limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome way to abuse Excel! Seriously, I like it, I learnt something.

You might however be better served with something a Google search for "printable grid" and some scrolling turned up, I will let the URL speak:

http://www.printablepaper.net/preview/grid-portrait-a4-4mm

They have roughly a cubic lightyear of grid-pdfs for free download. I hope A4 is alright for you, otherwise I suppose they have that on letter or whatever as well.

btw. at least your tags are a clear case of the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This is not an Excel-Question at all really. :-) Fortunately you stated your ultimate goal. Hope this gets you the precision you need.