# Using Excel to create calculation sheets with a 5mm grid

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, grid

In my office we have calculation pads for hand writing calculations. I also have some spreadsheets I use and would like to make them look the same. I have a few problems.

1. Setting a 5mm grid. I found that you can't set a grid to exactly 5mm. [Using Excel to make a grid in millimeters](https://superuser.com/questions/736337/using-excel-to-make-a-grid-in-millimeters).

   I can work around this by setting 2 columns slightly wider than 5mm, and the 3rd column slightly under 5mm, to get an approximate average. (I found that it doesn't actually print the size is says anyway, 5.03 was coming out slightly larger than this). I have printed with a grey grid successfully.
2. The problem I'm having is that when I have a number with 3 digits or more, it doesn't fit within the cell and turns into a #.

   What I would like is for it to continue over the top of the next cell, as happens with text.
3. When I insert our company logo (as a picture), I can't see the gridlines.

   Can this be changed?
4. Perhaps I could scan our calculation pad and set it as a watermark?

   I haven't figured out how to do this.

Comment: maybe copying the whole table to Word and format it there would be a good workaround

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get a 5.01 mm by 5.01 mm grid by adjusting the print scaling settings.

Under Page Setup | Scaling, change the value to 10%. Then adjust the row height and the column width to 5 mm and Excel will round it to 5.01 mm.

Keep in mind that a font size of 60 points at 10% scaling will print at 6 points. A 3-digit number of 6-point Calibri will display in a cell with width 5.01 mm.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with points and "character widths" that vary by font, switch to "Page Layout" view.

In "Page Layout" view, one can use real measurements like "mm" and "in" for BOTH height and width. So not only are you directly specifying the measurement you desire, you are working in the same units for both height and width which is essential for square boxes such as a graph-like grid has.